# Error occurs when importing framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Install framer-motion and
import { Frame, useMotionValue, useTransform } from 'framer';. However, I get the following error.

```
Cannot find module 'framer' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Comment: [framer-motion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion) has its own TypeScript declarations so, you need to install the framer-motion only. Have you tried `yarn add framer-motion`? And tell me your framer-motion version as seen in package.json file? You don't need `framer`, you just need `framer-motion` for React App. Try [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-react-framer-motion-qdx6l?file=/src/App.tsx) or [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zokwh?file=/src/index.js:34-42)

Comment: The version is "framer-motion": "3.10.6".

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i framer-motion
```

after:

```
import { useMotionValue, useTransform } from "framer-motion"
import { Frame } from "framer"
```

You misunderstood "framer-motion" and "framer"

Answer (score 0):

You installed framer-motion right? Then you will have to import from that lib itself!

**You do like this :**

```
import { Frame, useMotionValue, useTransform } from "framer-motion"
```

Comment: Yes.Module '"framer-motion"' has no exported member 'Frame'.ts(2305)An error will be displayed.

Comment: then dont import it

Comment: hi, when i install framer-motion i dont see it in package.json nor inside my node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, although `framer-motion` had been working perfectly fine before then.

**## How I solved it**

I deleted the node_modules folder and then ran `yarn add framer-motion` again.

And the error is gone.

Comment: After deleting `node_modules` you would normally only need to run `yarn`. The fact that you had to run `yarn add framer-motion` probably means that you did not have it installed for some reason. In that case your answer would be a duplicate of the existing answer that recommended installing it with npm.